# How can a powerless entity affect calamities around the world?

Tags: planets, secret-society

This is a follow-up question.
[How can I make my sealing ritual neccessary?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/161785/how-can-i-make-my-sealing-ritual-neccessary?noredirect=1#comment507533_161785)

The scarlett king is an ancient entity that exists across multiple dimensions, and seeks to enter our world. When the child of the 7th bride was eventually born, it was taken in by the scp foundation and designated 231-45. This child would be raised as a human by the foundation in service to humanity.

However, the coming of the Scarlett king caused an incident which would live in infamy around the planet. On Friday the 13th, the day it was born, earthquakes, tsunamis, and other natural disasters spontaneously occurred with no explicable warning in various countries, leading to the deaths of 5 million people. The foundation have linked this strange occurrence with the birth of the child. However, this reason is illogical. Due to the death of the six brides, the king was never able to fully materialize into our world. Although powerful, it was a baby and weak enough to be controlled with the various incantations and sigils that the foundation laid in preparation for it.

I need a way to link these two incidents together. How can I make this happen?

Comment: [Reminder to close-voters](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3773/6986): The problem cannot be fixed if the OP is not made aware of it.

Comment: That being said, I tend to agree with closing this question. We cannot predict earthquakes because they don't give warnings, neither do tornadoes. Tsunamis are predictable because we can watch them crossing the ocean and we know what causes them (earthquakes are a major reason). But linking unpredictable events to a magical event is going to be... magical, which puts this in the _too story-based_ or _primarily opinion-based_ category of questions.

Comment: Maybe it wasn't the (powerless) child, but the (powerful) incantations and sigils used to render the child powerless?  I can't imagine anything so powerful that earthquakes and tsunamis are a "powerless" consequence of, being bound without a lot of trouble... and, really, since this seems like a unheard-of event, having some of those incantations and sigils have high collateral damage, or unforeseen consequences, or interact badly in some areas, or have some outright fail, (and final success occurring because there were redundant rituals), would seem to make intuitive sense.

Answer (score 4):

The child's existence is the key to a metaphysical doorway which is one layer of a multiple layer barrier between our world and the plane where the Scarlett King waits.  This doorway is the outermost layer of the barrier, the layer closest to our world.

The six brides would have opened all of the other layers of the barrier if they had lived, but since they didn't, those layers remained closed, blocking the Scarlett King's access to our world.

The doorway, being closest to our world, interacts with our world more than any of the other layers.  Tectonic plates whose massive size and density transcend the purely physical world, rest metaphysically up against the doorway.  The doorway's presence also partially suppresses the formation of hurricanes and the gathering of locust swarms.  It even weakens the lethal nature of plague viruses, not eliminating them entirely, but dramatically lessening their propagation and death counts.

When the child is born, the doorway opens then ceases to exist.  When this happens, all of the side effects of the doorway's existence ends.  Tectonic plates, no longer supported by the doorway's presence, suddenly shift, causing earthquakes and tsunamis.  Hurricanes and locust swarms form more quickly than when the doorway stood closed.  Plagues surge across the world with deadly effect.

It is not the child which causes the calamities.  All the child did was fulfill the termination requirements of the ancient Doorway spell.  It is the termination of that spell and the subsequent ending of the Doorway spell's side effects, which ultimately causes all of the calamities and disasters.

Answer (score 1):

**You don't have the mark. You got the Father of the mark. Oopsie!**

*The seas arise amisdt moving earth.

For the maker of the unmaker breathes once again.*

Look into many religions and myths as reference.  Even the side charcters of the Main Character were of great import. Mary mother JC was said to receive the visit of an angel. Goddess Kali, spouse of Shiva, left her footprint in the world.

Maybe the babe grows and realises he was a hostage all along and in trying to prevent the future, your SCP goons sealed its own fate.